# too many logitech K350 keyboards showing in device manager

Tags: windows-7

i have a logitech K350 and a trackball m570 running through ONE logitech unifying receiver installed on my self built $1500.00 gaming computer. In fact the problem just arose while typing here.

Problem is the damn frickin]g keybaord wont display what i fricking type all the damn time and i've already spoken to a logitech rep on the phone about why whenever i restart my win7 home premium computer the damn thing wont type half the damn time. If you can't fricking understand how irritating that is then dont reply to this.

I've removed 3 extra "logitech HID-compliant Unifying Keyboard" listings under device manager every time i restart the OS. I've never ever had a problem with the Logitech compliant M570 trackball. SO i doubt it's the unifying software receiver.

I've also just found that listed under device manager/ Human interface devices i have 3 HID consumer compliant devices, 6 HID compliant devices, 4 logitech HID compliant unifying devices.... wtf do i need all those damn things for????

If i install a new device then and only damn then should the stupid OS add something new to this listing and if i ever remove/uninstall a piece of hardware, then and only then should the OS remove something within the "device manager" but then this crap is American in design, so who the hell knows what actually does work correctly.

oh yes, now miraculously, for the past 3 paragraphs, the keyboard and display screen have finally synced each other to where they can function as they should and every key hit is actually showing up in the correct order.

This is crap. I want to know why these 2 items... namely the same display and K350 keyboard keep having these wireless issues for the past 3 months that i've had this keyboard? Oh and yes, i do know and understand more than enough about electronics and wireless signal transfer to be really really angry when this crap happens at all which it shouldn't.

SO why do i need all of these darn HID devices at all. I have one logitech M570 trackman and ONE K350 wireless keyboard installed on this computer. NO other computers are EVER withing 25 feet of this computer?

thanks and sorry for ranting, but i am human and we are designed to attach anger with the things that anger us.